Где главное, а где зависимое слово в словосочетаниях?
1. красный от огня
2. ничего не рассказать


Красный от огня.  Предложное управление Р. п. со стороны прилагательного, которое является главным словом.

Рассказать что. Управление В. п. со стороны глагола, прямое дополнение что. Ничего не рассказать. Управление Р. п. при наличии отрицания, также прямое дополнение ничего. Глагол — главное слово.


